# On 1st page footer have gone

Tags: microsoft-word, images, microsoft-word-2016, headers, footers

I need to create a document in word 2016,where the footer on the first page should disappear, if I have enough text to reach the 2nd page.

Why this happen? Does anyone has any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: check that you don't have the option different first page set.  Often people don't want a page number on the cover of a document.

Comment: Thanks. I am making thesis paper. I need the page number on the first page.

Comment: You will want to check that then in the header/footer settings.  Also, if you inserted section breaks that can affect whether or not the formatting is consistent between pages in different sections.

Comment: I would suggest you [show Paragraph marks](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/show-or-hide-tab-marks-in-word-84a53213-5d02-404a-b022-09cae1a3958b) to check the Section Break.

Answer (score 0):

### Page Numbers are Directly Connected to Headers and Footers

You need to look at those. If [Different First Page](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#Different_First_Page) is selected for your footer, you will need to add the page number separately on the first page or change the setting so that your Footer says "Footer" rather than "First-Page Footer."

The different first page setting applies to both the header and footer together, so if you have a header you do not want on your first page, you will need to keep that setting and simply add a page number to the footer of that page.

**Page Numbers** are dynamic *fields*, normally. If you do want Different First Page set, you could simply type a "1" for your page one instead of a field since it does not need to be dynamic.

Headers and Footers are set in **Sections**. It appears that your first page has at least three sections because changing columns changes sections. If you directly edit the footer it will show which section controls the footer.

[image: screenshot]

**Note:** The controls on the Mac are slightly different, but the principles are the same.

Here is my [recap of header and footer settings](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#Recap_of_Header/Footer_settings). Here is my writing on [Page Numbering in Word](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#PageNumbers). All links are to my page on Sections.